# What property to use in kafka mysql source connector to register a new version for any schema change

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry, debezium

This is the configuration of schema-registry.properties

```
listeners=http://10.X.X.76:8081
kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://10.XXX:9092,PLAINTEXT://10.XXX:9092,PLAINTEXT://10.XXXX.1:9092,PLAINTEXT://1XXXX.69:9092
kafkastore.topic=_schemas
debug=false
master.eligibility=true
```

This is the configuration of my connector,

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
  "snapshot.locking.mode": "minimal",
  "database.user": "cdc_user",
  "tasks.max": "3",
  "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "10.49.115.249:9092,10.48.130.211:9092,10.54.178.121:9092,10.53.4.69:9092",
  "database.history.kafka.topic": "history.cdc.fkw.supply.mp.seller_facility",
  "database.server.name": "cdc.fkw.supply.mp",
  "heartbeat.interval.ms": "5000",
  "database.port": "3306",
  "table.whitelist": "seller_facility.addresses, seller_facility.location, seller_facility.default_location, seller_facility.location_document_mapping",
  "database.hostname": "dog-rr.ffb-supply-ffb-supply-mp.prod.altair.fkcloud.in",
  "database.password": "6X5DpJrVzI",
  "database.history.kafka.recovery.poll.interval.ms": "5000",
  "name": "cdc.fkw.supply.mp.seller_facility.connector",
  "database.history.skip.unparseable.ddl": "true",
  "errors.tolerance": "all",
  "database.whitelist": "seller_facility",
  "snapshot.mode": "when_needed"
}
```

How do I register a new schema when there is any change in the schema?
What property can I add to do so, so that it just adds a new version to schema registry for that particular topic and is fully compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `key`/`value.converter` are using one of the Confluent ones, such as `AvroConverter` for example, any new/removed database columns will automatically be picked up by the Connect framework, and registered to the Registry as part of the serialization in the `KafkaAvroSerializer` process.

Changing the database column types might generate errors, for example, changing `VARCHAR` to `INT`